# Ehcache getting out of sync with database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, ehcache, race-condition

On a Java EE server using CMT, I am using ehcache to implement a caching layer between the business object layer (EJBs) and the Data Access layer (POJOs using JDBC).  I seem to be experiencing a race condition between two threads accessing the same record while using a self-populating Ehcache.  The cache is keyed on the primary key of the record.

The scenario is:

1. The first thread updates the record in the database and removes the record from cache (but the database commit doesn't necessarily happen immediately - there may be other queries to follow.)
2. The second thread reads the record, causing the cache to be re-populated.
3. The first thread commits transaction.

This is all happening in a fraction of a second.  It results in the cache being out of sync with the database, and subsequent reads of the record returning the stale cached data until another update is performed, or the entry expires from the cache.  I can handle stale data for short periods (the typical length of a transaction), but not minutes, which is how long I would like to cache objects.

Any suggestions for avoiding this race condition?

**UPDATE:**

Clearing the cache after the transaction has committed would certainly be ideal.  The question is, in a J2EE environment using CMT, when the caching layer is sandwiched between the business layer (stateless session EJBs) and the data access layer, how to do this?

To be clear about the constraints this imposes, the method call in question may or may not be in the same transaction as additional method calls that happen before or after.  I can't force a commit (or do this work in a separate transaction) since that would change the transaction boundaries from what the client code expects.  Any subsequent exceptions would not roll back the entire transaction (unneseccarily clearing the cache in this case is an acceptable side-effect).  I can't control the entry points into the transaction, as it is essentially an API that clients can use.  It is not reasonable to push the resonsiblity of clearing the cache to the client application.

I would like to be able to defer any cache clearing operations until the entire transaction is committed by the EJB container, but I have found no way to hook into that logic and run my own code with a stateless session bean.

**UPDATE #2:**

The most promising solution so far, short of a major design change, is to use ehcache 2.0's JTA support: http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/jta

This means upgrading to ehcache 2.x and enabling XA transactions for the database as well, which could potentially have negative side-effects.  But it seems like the "right" way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using transactions - it makes more sense to remove the cache **after** the `commit`, that is when the change really happens.

That way you see the old data only during the length of the transaction, and all reads afterwards have the latest view.

**Update:** Since this is CMT specific, you should look at the [SessionSynchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html) interface, and it's [afterCompletion()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html#afterCompletion%28boolean%29) method. This is showed in [this tutorial.](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html#62994)

Comment: Of course this is ideal, but HOW to do this?  I have updated the question to clarify the constraints.

Comment: Hi Kril, the SessionSynchronization interface is only available for Stateful Session Beans.. it would certainly be a great solution if it was available for stateless as well.